# Can someone view html files of a WP7 application after downloading it from the marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm new to developing applications using phonegap and windows phone 7.

I learnt that while an application is running in the emulator, we can use Isolated Storage Explorer tool to retrieve the application's local folder. From the copy of the local folder, we are able to see files like index.html and other html files of application.

My question here is: When someone downloads my application from marketplace(developed using phonegap and WP7), will they be able to see my html files using Isolated Storage Explorer in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [WP7 Root Tools](http://wp7roottools.com/) to do the same thing as the Isolated Storage Explorer.

The *Applications* folder in the root contains the *Data* and *Install* folders, from which you can access isolated storage or the installed files and DLLs for any installed app. Note that this requires root access, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Simon. So I can take that it is possible to view html files after installation application in windows phone from market place?

Comment: I tried it on my phone, and I was able to see html files and pngs. I could view the .png files, but not the .html files, but I assume that was simply due to the viewer I was using, as there's no reason why .html files would be any less accessible than the images.